# Enviar archivo adjunto desde cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

Que tal.
Tengo un archivo que debo rescatar en una máquina en la cual la única manera que he podido entrar es por línea de comandos, por lo tanto quiero saber es como enviarme ese archivo por medio de correo electrónico o copiando el archivo de una IP a otra , o alguna otra opción donde pueda rescatar ese archivo por medio de la línea de comandos.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias opciones y unas más fáciles que otras en función de los sistemas operativos que uses.

Lo más compatible y también sencillo es pasártelo por FTP ya que en el CMD ya tienes un cliente de FTP, lo único que necesitas es un servidor FTP.

Puedes montarte el servidor en otro ordenador que esté en la misma red con Filezilla https://filezilla-project.org/. (La versión servidor no el cliente)

Y una vez que lo tienes funcionando y te hayas creado un usuario y contraseña, solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:
1.-Te colocas en el directorio donde estén los ficheros a transmitir
2.-Escribes el comando siguiente

> *FTP direccionipdelservidor*

te preguntará usuario y password

3.-Escribes el comando *bin* para que transfiera en modo fichero

4.-Por cada fichero a transmitir haces un

> *put nombrefichero.extension*

Y si quieres copiar mas de uno a la vez

> *mput patrondeficheros *

Otra opción es pasártelo por la red mediante samba o compartición de ficheros.

En el equipo al que vayas a enviar los ficheros, compartes una carpeta  ( botón derecho propiedades, compartir, compartir, pones un nombre y añades a Todos todos los permisos).

A continuación en el equipo donde has entrado por consola escribes:

> *NET USE z: \direccionip\nombrequehaspuesto *

A partir de ahora en el equipo al que has accedido por consola, tendrás una nueva unidad Z: a la que copiar lo que quieras:

COPY fichero z:\

Lo que escribas en Z lo tendrás en la carpeta compartida del otro equipo.

Answer (score -1):

Te ofrezco otra alternativa. Existe un comando en cmd llamado ROBOCOPY, te permitirá pasar una carpeta a otra dirección, como por ejemplo una USB (E:) yo lo usé y me funcionó una vez. Así mandas tu archivo a una memoria.